# passing a list of values in where condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a controller code, where I want to filter values of sales rep which are present in User table but not present in User_Stats table. For this purpose, I am trying to pass a list of values of sales rep in where condition.. but it is not recognizing  `where Sales_Rep__c not in [Select ...]` part. Please help

Controller:

```
 public list <SelectOption> getAddosr()
{
    list <selectoption> lsosradd = new List<selectoption> ();
    lsosradd.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
    Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
    list<String> newString = [SELECT Sales_Rep__c FROM User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0];
    Set<String> repSet1 = new Set<String>();
    for (User srep :  [SELECT Sales_Rep__c FROM User where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0 and Sales_Rep__c != null and Sales_Rep__c NOT IN: newString])
    {
        if(!repSet1.contains(srep.Sales_Rep__c)) lsosradd.add(new selectoption(srep.Sales_Rep__c, srep.Sales_Rep__c));
        repSet1.add(srep.Sales_Rep__c);
    }
    return lsosradd;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You query seems wrong:

```
 [SELECT Sales_Rep__c FROM User where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0 and Sales_Rep__c != null and Sales_Rep__c not in 
 (SELECT Sales_Rep__c FROM User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0) 
  ORDER BY Sales_Rep__c]
```

Inner query must start with `"("` and close with `")"` e.g; `[SELECT id FROM Account WHERE id in (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact)]`

**UPDATE**

```
        public list <SelectOption> getAddosr()
        {
            List <selectoption> lsosradd = new List<selectoption> ();
            lsosradd.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
            Integer regnInt = (regn!=null) ? Integer.valueOf(regn) : -1;
            List<String> newString = new List<String>();
            for(User_Stats__c ust : [SELECT Sales_Rep__c FROM User_Stats__c where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0])
            {
                newString.add(ust.Sales_Rep__c);
            }
            Set<String> repSet1 = new Set<String>();
            for (User srep :  [SELECT Sales_Rep__c FROM User where Region__c =: regnInt and District__c =: dist and District__c != null and Region__c != null and Region__c != 1 and Region__c != 0 and Sales_Rep__c != null and Sales_Rep__c NOT IN: newString])
            {
                if(!repSet1.contains(srep.Sales_Rep__c)) 
                        lsosradd.add(new selectoption(srep.Sales_Rep__c, srep.Sales_Rep__c));
                repSet1.add(srep.Sales_Rep__c);
            }
            return lsosradd;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks regal. The code that you suggested gives this error. `Error: semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use: 'Sales_Rep__c'` What does this mean?

Comment: This is happening because 'SalesRep__c' is a text field and you are comparing relationship with Id field. Solution for this is save all those Ids in a `List<String>` and then add to query as: `NOT IN: newStringList`. @Robin

Comment: I have updated my code (above) to incorporate your suggestion. However, the `List<String>` step gives an error of **illegal assignment from List<User_Stats__c> to List<String>**. Sorry I am new to this. Thanks.

Comment: No, You are doing wrong. Updated my answer. @Robin

Answer (score 1):

Here is some new code (I assumed that those objects are not related - I will change it as soon as you will provide me with some info)

```
// Set and query to gather string values from object
Set<String> salesReps = new Set<String>();

for(String salesRep: [  SELECT Sales_Rep__c 
                        FROM User_Stats__c 
                        WHERE   Region__c =: regnInt AND District__c =: dist 
                        AND District__c != null 
                        AND Region__c != null 
                        AND Region__c != 1 
                        AND Region__c != 0){

    salesReps.add(salesRep.Sales_Rep__c);                        
}
// actual query 
[SELECT Sales_Rep__c 
 FROM User 
 WHERE  Region__c =:   regnInt 
        AND District__c =: dist 
        AND District__c != null 
        AND Region__c != null 
        AND Region__c != 1 
        AND Region__c != 0 
        AND Sales_Rep__c != null 
        AND Sales_Rep__c NOT IN : salesReps
ORDER BY Sales_Rep__c];
```

Comment: Thanks Birthus. The code that you suggested gives this error. `Error: semi join sub selects can only query id fields, cannot use: 'Sales_Rep__c'` How can I solve this?

Comment: Is Sales_Rep__c  a look up to an object?

Comment: I guess not. And that why you get error. The easiest solution will be to split this in 2 queries.